# How to map a hash key with a list of values in c#?

Tags: c#, hashmap, hashtable, hash

I have a string member variable namely ServiceType and a string list SubService .

Here serviceType contains strings(consider as key) and SubService contains list of

strings(consider as value). Now i'm trying to map one ServiceType string(key) with

SubService(value contains list of strings) using hashing concept. what my problem is i can map

a key with one value but i'm not getting that how to map with list of values.Anyone can help

me that hoe to map this kind of list and key in c#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you need `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your reply now i got it and i will do

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Visual Studio open in front of me, so this probably has some syntax issues, but basically:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> foo = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
// populate
List<string> bar = new List<string>();
bar.Add("wheeeee");
foo.Add("myKeyValue", bar);
// fetch
List<string> myServices = foo["myKeyValue"];
```

Comment: Hi thank you i'm done and my problem is solved with your solution.